# CSS styling issue in mobile view

Tags: css

Text showing like below in mobile view:

```
    Start your text
here
```

Expected output:

```
    Start your text
    here
```

On applying left padding of 15px the content is shifted but in mobile view when the string is flowing to the next line then it is flowing towards left side. Text "here" should start from the same coordinates as the text "Start".

Comment: Hi, Welcome, Please add your code - See here for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add some code sample what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some kind of code like this

```
<div style="background-color: #aaa;padding: 15px;">
    <p>Start your text</p>
    here
</div>
```